# Get color for web table cell

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I have web table where a green row color indicates valid data and a red row indicates invalid data. See this screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWqxM.jpg

I can get the count of rows and the values but don't know how to get the color of each row in the table.

Below is the code for getting row count and value.

```
boolean ispresent = foxdriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_CP_gvI']/tbody/tr/td")).size()!=0;
if (ispresent = true) {
    List<WebElement> drup = foxdriver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_CP_gvI']/tbody/tr/td"));
    int druplst = drup.size();
    System.out.println(druplst);
    for (int x=2; x <= druplst; x++) {
        String drupname = foxdriver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_CP_gvI']/tbody/tr["+x+"]/td[1]")).getText().trim();
        System.out.println(drupname);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to give a sample of the HTML which makes up the table. Are the row colours hardcoded into `style` attributes, or are they applied through CSS stylesheets which target `class` and/or `id` attributes in the table rows and cells?

Comment: Actually it is a gridview and color is given in C#.net back end code which is hardcoded based on conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve **rgba** values from **background-color**(**In general scenarios**)

For eg. on this page, in the code part, u can get the background:

```
WebElement ele = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//pre"));
System.out.println(ele.getCssValue("background-color"));
```

this will provide you o/p - **rgba(238, 238, 238, 1)** so you can implement same in your case and notify difference in string meaning red or green.